# Connect to SVN repository with Netbeans using SVN+SSH

Tags: java, svn, netbeans

I am trying to connect to a SVN server in order to import my project into it with svn+ssh authentication method. I am using the NetBeans IDE (6.8) with subversion plugin installed on Windows XP SP2. I have plink installed with its path set in the Windows PATH env variable. When I use the similar looking repository URL (XXXX and YYYY replaced with sensible things)

```
svn+ssh://XXXX@YYYY/home/dce/svn/trunk
```

along with this external tunnel command

```
plink -l <myUserName> -i C:\\privateKey.ppk
```

I keep getting this error:

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

I searched about it on the Internet and tried many things but didn't work out. Please help if anybody has some idea what may be going wrong. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is their some specific configuration or settings that I might be missing?

Comment: Have you verified that a svn client will work from the command line?

Comment: Did you find the answer? I have a similar problem...

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up switching to Eclipse and it worked seamlesely.